# Apache Camel File End Point - Reading the file one by one sorted in the created order

Tags: java, apache-camel, websphere

Requesting for the Help with Apache Camel 2.15.3.
An Endpoint is configured to take files from a folder and process it. It works in a way that data from the file will be uploaded (inserts/updates) to multiple tables using Java Application.
Configured Endpoint is

```
<endpoint id="batchFilesFolder" uri="file:///C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/APP/Batch/" />
```

Throughout the day the files will come to this folder, sometime multiple files together. Now if there are multiple files, the different threads is taking it for processing and posting it db creates contention.

Now I would like to have a perfect file endpoint point options, that will

1. Read and process one file at a time. With a proper delay after processing.
2. Read order must be in the order of creation of file.

Can you please help? I have tried putting the delay,maxMessagesPerPoll etc, but it is not working..like below -

```
<endpoint id="batchFilesFolder" uri="file:///C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/APP/Batch/?delay=300000&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=1" />
```

Comment: looks like some of your question is missing after the "is" on the third line.  If you entered any tags.  They need to be indented with 4 spaces on a separate line with an extra line between the text.

Comment: you may want to look at Implementing Processors that Use the AsyncProcessor API.

Comment: Thanks @dskow for pointing this out. I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a small test using files with a modified date difference of 1 sec:

`for i in {1..10}; do echo $i >> file$i; sleep 1 ; done;`

The endpoint:

```
<endpoint id="batchFilesFolder" uri="file:///C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/APP/Batch/?maxMessagesPerPoll=1&amp;eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false&amp;sortBy=file:modified&amp;delay=1000" />
```

The trick here is the `eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll` to [sort your files](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) and then process it:

> Allows for controlling whether the limit from **maxMessagesPerPoll** is eager or not. If eager then the limit is during the scanning of files. W**here as false would scan all files, and then perform sorting. Setting this option to false allows for sorting all files first, and then limit the poll**. Mind that this requires a higher memory usage as all file details are in memory to perform the sorting.

Be aware that your memory will grown while performing the sort.

The result of the test was:

```
INFO 18103 --- [resources/file2] route1                                   : file1
INFO 18103 --- [resources/file2] route1                                   : file2
INFO 18103 --- [resources/file2] route1                                   : file3
INFO 18103 --- [resources/file2] route1                                   : file4
INFO 18103 --- [resources/file2] route1                                   : file5
INFO 18103 --- [resources/file2] route1                                   : file6
INFO 18103 --- [resources/file2] route1                                   : file7
INFO 18103 --- [resources/file2] route1                                   : file8
INFO 18103 --- [resources/file2] route1                                   : file9
INFO 18103 --- [resources/file2] route1                                   : file10
```

The route used for this test:

```
@Override
protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("file:src/test/resources/file2?noop=true&maxMessagesPerPoll=1&eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false&sortBy=file:modified&delay=1000")
                .log("${in.header.CamelFileName}")
                .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                .to("mock:result");
        }
    };
}
```

You also may consider taking a look at the `readLock` property to control how your route should read the files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a quartz2-scheduler to poll, say, every 10 seconds along with the `maxMessagesPerPoll` and `sortBy` options:

```
<endpoint id="batchFilesFolder" uri="file:///C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/APP/Batch/?scheduler=quartz2&amp;scheduler.cron=0/10+*+*+*+*+?&amp;sortBy=reverse:file:modified&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=1" />
```

The docs are a bit unclear about whether `file:modified` looks for the newest or oldest file, so if my example gives you the newest file just remove `reverse:`.